# Pandas: decompress date range to individual dates

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

**Dataset:** I have a 1GB dataset of stocks, which have values between date ranges. There is no overlapping in date ranges and the dataset is sorted on (ticker, start_date).

```
>>> df.head()
             start_date    end_date                   val    
ticker         
AAPL         2014-05-01  2014-05-01         10.0000000000
AAPL         2014-06-05  2014-06-10         20.0000000000
GOOG         2014-06-01  2014-06-15         50.0000000000
MSFT         2014-06-16  2014-06-16                  None
TWTR         2014-01-17  2014-05-17         10.0000000000
```

**Goal:** I want to decompress the dataframe so that I have individual dates instead of date ranges. For example, the AAPL rows would go from being only 2 rows to 7 rows:

```
>>> AAPL_decompressed.head()
                   val
date                       
2014-05-01         10.0000000000
2014-06-05         20.0000000000
2014-06-06         20.0000000000
2014-06-07         20.0000000000
2014-06-08         20.0000000000
```

I'm hoping there's a nice optimized method from pandas like resample that can do this in a couple lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bit more than a few lines, but I think it results in what you asked:

Starting with your dataframe:

```
In [70]: df
Out[70]:
       start_date   end_date  val  row
ticker
AAPL   2014-05-01 2014-05-01   10    0
AAPL   2014-06-05 2014-06-10   20    1
GOOG   2014-06-01 2014-06-15   50    2
MSFT   2014-06-16 2014-06-16  NaN    3
TWTR   2014-01-17 2014-05-17   10    4
```

First I reshape this dataframe to a dataframe with one `date` column (so every row two times repeated for each date of `start_date` and `end_date` (and I add a counter column called `row`):

```
In [60]: df['row'] = range(len(df))
In [61]: starts = df[['start_date', 'val', 'row']].rename(columns={'start_date': 'date'})
In [62]: ends = df[['end_date', 'val', 'row']].rename(columns={'end_date':'date'})
In [63]: df_decomp = pd.concat([starts, ends])
In [64]: df_decomp = df_decomp.set_index('row', append=True)
In [65]: df_decomp.sort_index()
Out[65]:
                 date  val
ticker row
AAPL   0   2014-05-01   10
       0   2014-05-01   10
       1   2014-06-05   20
       1   2014-06-10   20
GOOG   2   2014-06-01   50
       2   2014-06-15   50
MSFT   3   2014-06-16  NaN
       3   2014-06-16  NaN
TWTR   4   2014-01-17   10
       4   2014-05-17   10
```

Based on this new dataframe, I can group it by `ticker` and `row`, and apply a daily `resample` on each of these groups and `fillna` (with method 'pad' to forward fill)

```
In [66]: df_decomp = df_decomp.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('D').fillna(method='pad'))

In [67]: df_decomp = df_decomp.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

The last command was to drop the now superfluous `row` index level.
When we access the AAPL rows, it gives your desired output:

```
In [69]: df_decomp.loc['AAPL']
Out[69]:
            val
date
2014-05-01   10
2014-06-05   20
2014-06-06   20
2014-06-07   20
2014-06-08   20
2014-06-09   20
2014-06-10   20
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Please ignore my previous comment, I was mistaken.

Comment: @joris is there any way to do the resampling if val is of mixed type? My val column can also have dates and strings in it.

Comment: The problem is that val gets dropped if it's non-numeric.

Comment: Yes, an easy solution is to add `how='first'` in the `resample` call (the default is `mean`, which does not work with non-numeric values). The result will be the same in your case. But apart from that, it is not really recommended to have such a mixed dtype (also other operations you could want to do will have this problem)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in five steps:

1) filter the ticker column to find the stock you want

2) use `pandas.bdate_range` to build a list of date ranges between `start` and `end`

3) flatten this list using `reduce`

4) reindex your new filtered dataframe

5) fill nans using the method `pad`

Here is the code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import datetime

>>> data = [('AAPL', datetime.date(2014, 4, 28), datetime.date(2014, 5, 2), 90),
            ('AAPL', datetime.date(2014, 5, 5), datetime.date(2014, 5, 9), 80),
            ('MSFT', datetime.date(2014, 5, 5), datetime.date(2014, 5, 9), 150),
            ('AAPL', datetime.date(2014, 5, 12), datetime.date(2014, 5, 16), 85)]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['ticker', 'start', 'end', 'val'])

>>> df_new = df[df['ticker'] == 'AAPL']
>>> df_new.name = 'AAPL'
>>> df_new.index = df_new['start']
>>> df_new.index.name = 'date'
>>> df_new.index = df_new.index.to_datetime()

>>> from functools import reduce #for py3k only
>>> new_index = [pd.bdate_range(**d) for d in df_new[['start','end']].to_dict('record')]
>>> new_index_flat = reduce(pd.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex.append, new_index)

>>> df_new = df_new.reindex(new_index_flat)
>>> df_new = df_new.fillna(method='pad')
>>> df_new
               ticker       start         end  val
    2014-04-28   AAPL  2014-04-28  2014-05-02   90
    2014-04-29   AAPL  2014-04-28  2014-05-02   90
    2014-04-30   AAPL  2014-04-28  2014-05-02   90
    2014-05-01   AAPL  2014-04-28  2014-05-02   90
    2014-05-02   AAPL  2014-04-28  2014-05-02   90
    2014-05-05   AAPL  2014-05-05  2014-05-09   80
    2014-05-06   AAPL  2014-05-05  2014-05-09   80
    2014-05-07   AAPL  2014-05-05  2014-05-09   80
    2014-05-08   AAPL  2014-05-05  2014-05-09   80
    2014-05-09   AAPL  2014-05-05  2014-05-09   80
    2014-05-12   AAPL  2014-05-12  2014-05-16   85
    2014-05-13   AAPL  2014-05-12  2014-05-16   85
    2014-05-14   AAPL  2014-05-12  2014-05-16   85
    2014-05-15   AAPL  2014-05-12  2014-05-16   85
    2014-05-16   AAPL  2014-05-12  2014-05-16   85

    [15 rows x 4 columns]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately your example above doesn't solve the problem because, for example, I'd want rows for dates 2014-05-05 up to 2014-05-11. Also note that the data set you're using has an error in that AAPL's date range in row 3 overlaps with that in row 1.

Comment: Understood. It is to do that from here, all we need to do is sort, resample and fill the series. Let me change the answer.

Comment: **EDIT**: @tuva, I have edited the answer to reflect your comment. I used non-overlapping dates now, spanning 3 weeks but the intervals don't really need to be regular; what is really important though is that the start dates **must** be business dates, otherwise reindex will cause that interval to be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky way to do it - I post this poor answer (remember - I can't code :-) ) because I am new to pandas and would not mind someone improving it.

This reads the file that had the data originally posted - then creates a multi-index off of the stock_id and the end_date.  The get_val function below takes the entire frame, a ticker e.g. 'AAPL', and a date and uses index.searchsorted which behaves like map::upper_bound in C++ - i.e. finds the index where the date would be inserted if you wanted to insert - i.e. find the enddate closest to, but after the date in question - this will have the value that we want and we return that with get_val.

Then I grab a cross section from a Series with this Multiindex based on the stock_id of 'AAPL'.  Then we form an empty list which will be used to flatten the list of tuples of dates from the multiindex with the key of 'AAPL'.  These dates become the index and values of a series.  Then I map this series to get_val to grab the stock price that is desired.

I know this is probably wrong...but...happy to learn.

I would not be surprised to find out that there is an easy way to inflate a data frame like this that uses some fill forward interpolation method...

```
stocks=pd.read_csv('stocks2.csv', parse_dates=['start_date', 'end_date'], index_col='ticker')
mi=zip(stocks.index, pd.Series(zip(stocks['start_date'],stocks['end_date'].values)).map(lambda z: tuple(pd.date_range(start=z[0], end=z[1]))).values)
mi=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(mi)
ticker='AAPL'
s=pd.Series(index=mi,data=0)
s=list(s.xs(key=ticker).index)
l=[]
map(lambda x: l.extend(x), s)
s=pd.Series(index=l,data=l)
stocks_byticker=stocks[stocks.index==ticker].set_index('end_date')
print(s.map(lambda x: stocks_byticker.ix[stocks_byticker.index.searchsorted(x), 'val']))

2014-05-01    10
2014-06-05    20
2014-06-06    20
2014-06-07    20
2014-06-08    20
2014-06-09    20
2014-06-10    20
```

Comment: Thanks for your submission. Just as FYI to everyone, I changed the dataset to tickers instead of stock_ids to make the question easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the question @tuva - the resample.fillna idiom above given by joris helped me with some stuff I was working on today.  I used custom business days for the sampling method which was a nice bonus feature - .resample(CDay(1, holidays=holiday_array)).etc
It still seems like there should be an easier solution that Pandas could provide.  It may be worth suggesting that the Pandas folks make a DataFrame.inflate(start_col,end_col,resample_freq, interp_method) function - it would be cool if the interp_method could work incrementally by using the previous value to calculate the next value.

Comment: Thanks @FinanceGuyThatCantCode. Glad we could both benefit from it. Maybe we can do a Pull Request to add that kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more general way to do this that expands on joris's good answer, but allows this to work with any number of additional columns:

```
import pandas as pd 

df['join_id'] = range(len(df)) 
starts = df[['start_date', 'join_id']].rename(columns={'start_date': 'date'})
ends = df[['end_date', 'join_id']].rename(columns={'end_date': 'date'})
start_end = pd.concat([starts, ends]).set_index('date')

fact_table = start_end.groupby("task_id").apply(lambda x: x.resample('D').fillna(method='pad'))
del fact_table["join_id"]
fact_table = fact_table.reset_index()
final = fact_table.merge(df, right_on='join', left_on='join', how='left')
```